# Windows Phone 7 Socket Class giving Host Not Found Error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asyncsocket, socketexception

I am using Socket class in Windows Phone SDK,

the thing is my application works fine on the emulator, but giving exceptation in the receive , saying

```
        // Make an asynchronous Send request over the socket
        _socket.SendToAsync(socketEventArg);
```

Invalid argument supplied,

When i debugged,  on send function, its saying "Host not found" but the same piece of code works fine in the Emulator,

I checked my device having Wi-FI and 3G both ,

Are there any app configuration that i am missing ?

Comment: what is the host, and how does it relate to the phone? is your phone on the same network if it is an internal address? etc?

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for the responding, in both the case , Emulator and Device, its accessing the Public network.